# Accounts Database

Tags: javascript, passwords

I am creating a website using html, js and css on Replit with a signup and login system and I am trying to figure out how to store the usernames and passwords.

I have tried making JavaScript arrays by doing:

```js
usernames = ["username1", "username2", "username3"]
passwords = ["password1", "password2", "password3"]
```

and then checking if the user inputted username and passwords are in the array and the placement number of each are the same but then anyone could go into inspect element or view source and see the passwords which is very bad for the security of the site. I have also tried putting them into a json file but the same thing applies. How could I store and retrieve the passwords securely?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to reinvent authentication. There are ready made solutions out there which don't rely on positionally matching usernames and plain-text passwords. Which will *protect* the passwords via decades old best practices.

Comment: How would I do that on Replit?

Comment: You don't. It's not really a secure environment. Anybody who will be using your app is running all the code of the app. By extension, they can spoof anything. You could get a third party authentication service to integrate with and thus reduce the attack vector, however, that's a hammer solution to a screwdriver problem.

Comment: Well are there any other free environments that don't require a download?